# Load additional controller using TestServer in .NET Core 3.1 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using the following code in my unit tests:

```
var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureWebHost(webHost =>
        {
            // Add TestServer
            webHost.UseTestServer();
            webHost.UseStartup<Startup>();

        });
```

I'd like to add a new controller only in the testserver. Is this somehow possible using the same StartUp in my normal und unit test project?

Update:
To make it clear:

I have my main controllers in MainProject.Controllers. When creating my TestServer in my UnitTestProject I want to additionally load UnitTestProject.Controllers (but only for the TestServer).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I found the answer:

I've derived a TestStartup (in my UnitTestProject) class from Startup. This seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new controller, you can just create new file under `ProjectName.Controller` namespace.

Comment: I have my main controllers in MainProject.Controllers. When creating my TestServerin my UnitTestProject I want to additionally load UnitTestProject.Controllers.